# declare a field of a struct as a function of others in Rust

Tags: inheritance, rust, struct

I have a struct A in Rust that has 3 fields, `a`, `b` and `c`

```rust
struct A {
  pub a: typeA,
  pub b: typeB,
  pub c: typeC
};
```

`typeA`, `typeB` and `typeC` are three different types of structs themselves. `typeB` and
`typeC` have `typeA` as depdendency. Like for example

```rust
struct typeB {
    pub bb: typeA,
};

struct typeC {
    pub cc: typeA,
};
```

And `typeA` is defined below as follows:

```rust
struct typeA {
    pub aa: String,
};
```

I can instantiate `A` like this:

```rust
let instance_a = A {
    a1 : typeA {aa: "a".to_string()},
    b1 : typeB {bb: typeA {aa: "a".to_string()}},
    c1 : typeC {cc: typeA {aa: "a".to_string()}},
};
```

As you can see `b1` and `c1` both depend on `a1` here.
My question is, is there a cleaner way to make the field `b1`
depend on `a1` directly at compile time without me having to
declare them separately in each case for `b1` and `c1`
as shown in `instance_a`?

The long term goal is to automatically update `b1` and `c1` as
`a1` gets modified. In other words, if I want to decide to
update the value of `a1` to this
`a1: typeA {aa : "b".to_string()}`
then `b1` and `c1` should automatically get updated.

I have tried approaching this problem in the following manner.
I have deduced `typeA`, `typeB` and `typeC` as cloneable.

```rust
impl A {
    pub fn create(a: &str) -> Self {
        let old_instance = typeA {aa : a.to_string()};
        A {
            a1: old_instance.clone(),
            b1: typeB {bb: old_instance.clone()},
            c1: typeC {cc: old_instance.clone()},
        }
    }
}
```

So whenever I want to update whatever is happening within `A`,
I just call `A::create("hello_world")`. The issue with this is
I am having to clone multiple times which I would like to avoid.

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/5397009

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to automatically update b and c when a is modified then you either want to hold references to a or you want to have mutual ownership with Arc. Arc is read only so if you want to modify stuff you need to do it with interior mutability. There are a few ways to do all that. Here is one (if you don't need mutiple threads replace Arc with Rc)

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::sync::Arc;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A {
    pub a: Arc<typeA>,
    pub b: typeB,
    pub c: typeC
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct typeB {
    pub bb: Arc<typeA>
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct typeC {
    pub cc: Arc<typeA>
}


#[derive(Debug)]
struct typeA {
    pub aa: RefCell<String>
}

fn main() {
    let mut aa = Arc::new(typeA { aa: RefCell::new(String::from("test1")) });
    let instance_a = A {
        a : aa.clone(),
        b : typeB {bb: aa.clone()},
        c : typeC {cc: aa.clone()},
    };
    println!("{:?}", instance_a);
    // modify aa
    *aa.aa.borrow_mut() = String::from("test2");
    println!("{:?}", instance_a);
}
```

Output:

```
A { a: typeA { aa: RefCell { value: "test1" } }, b: typeB { bb: typeA { aa: RefCell { value: "test1" } } }, c: typeC { cc: typeA { aa: RefCell { value: "test1" } } } }
A { a: typeA { aa: RefCell { value: "test2" } }, b: typeB { bb: typeA { aa: RefCell { value: "test2" } } }, c: typeC { cc: typeA { aa: RefCell { value: "test2" } } } }
```

Comment: Don't use references cause you can't move the struct anymore with them. Also `Arc` might be overkill unless you're writing concurrent code use `Rc` instead.

Comment: alright I'll remove the part with references to avoid confusion